# What happened to old Google Cloud SDK Debian packages?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

According to [the release notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes), the current Google Cloud SDK version is 334.0.0 and the previous 4 are (in reverse chronological order):

- 333.0.0
- 332.0.0
- 331.0.0
- 330.0.0

According to the [Recommended installation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) for Debian, I should be able to install any of these:

> If you'd like to revert to a specific version of Cloud SDK, where VERSION is of the form 123.0.0, run: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=123.0.0-0` The most recent ten releases will always be available in the repo.

However, today (2021-03-31) this only works for the current version. After running `sudo apt-get update` this works:

```
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=334.0.0-0
```

This does not:

```
$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=333.0.0-0
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '333.0.0-0' for 'google-cloud-sdk' was not found
```

Same result for the other 3 older versions.

I am using the documented repo:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

Where can I get the old Google Cloud SDK Debian packages?
Should I be using a different repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the package info for Debian Buster only appear the last two versions

https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk-buster/main/binary-amd64/Packages

```
Package: google-cloud-sdk
Version: 334.0.0-0
Installed-Size: 415484
Maintainer: Google Cloud SDK Authors <https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/>
Architecture: all
Depends: python3
Recommends: python3-crcmod
Suggests: google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java, google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python, google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator, google-cloud-sdk-bigtable-emulator, google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator, kubectl
Conflicts: gsutil
Description: Utilities for the Google Cloud Platform
Homepage: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Filename: pool/google-cloud-sdk_334.0.0-0_all_c2f14c2ea00cf8cca44f4b7b3fcdaa9de60c21334427ce7eee76520758f53c87.deb
Priority: optional
SHA256: c2f14c2ea00cf8cca44f4b7b3fcdaa9de60c21334427ce7eee76520758f53c87
Section: misc
Size: 69564766

Package: google-cloud-sdk
Version: 335.0.0-0
Installed-Size: 415998
Maintainer: Google Cloud SDK Authors <https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/>
Architecture: all
Depends: python3
Recommends: python3-crcmod
Suggests: google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java, google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python, google-cloud-sdk-pubsub-emulator, google-cloud-sdk-bigtable-emulator, google-cloud-sdk-datastore-emulator, kubectl
Conflicts: gsutil
Description: Utilities for the Google Cloud Platform
Homepage: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Filename: pool/google-cloud-sdk_335.0.0-0_all_c25a7d6d53fee880cb70f100f48ca4ae350ccc31baad39248738078a9eeeb114.deb
Priority: optional
SHA256: c25a7d6d53fee880cb70f100f48ca4ae350ccc31baad39248738078a9eeeb114
Section: misc
Size: 69828732
```

But in other repos, as Ubuntu Bionic or Debian Sid (unstable version) you can find all the versions

https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk-sid/main/binary-amd64/Packages
https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/cloud-sdk-bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages

Maybe it's an error in the Google package build, but if you update the apt source to sid it should work.

```
$ more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-buster main

$ apt list -a google-cloud-sdk
Listing... Done
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-buster,now 335.0.0-0 all [installed]
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-buster 334.0.0-0 all

# Update google-cloud-sdk.list file to sid and apt-get update

$ more /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-sid main

$ apt list -a google-cloud-sdk
Listing... Done
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid,now 335.0.0-0 all [installed]
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid 334.0.0-0 all
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid 333.0.0-0 all
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid 332.0.0-0 all
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid 331.0.0-0 all
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid 330.0.0-0 all
google-cloud-sdk/cloud-sdk-sid 329.0.0-0 all
....

$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk=333.0.0-0
....

$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 333.0.0
```

I have opened an error in the Google Issue Tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184651533

**Update 2021-04-19**: Google has fixed the issue and now the package contains previous versions (from 158.0.0-0 to 336.0.0-0)

Comment: I am awarding you the bonus for (a) correctly addressing the question asked, (b) opening an issue, and (c) providing a different repo from which to get packages. I am not going to make this the accepted answer, though, because the answer is incomplete (through no fault of your own). My guess is, given that the issue you opened is marked as blocked by a non-public issue, there is some security issue with the removed Debian packages and we will get more details after the disclosure blackout window has closed. If that is true and you come back and update the answer, I will accept it then.